Inkscape text not saving
I create Text in a circle using the command TEXT TO PATH in Inkscape and save as STL file.
I load into Snapmaker Luban and the text appears briefly and the disappears, leaving a circle ( which isn't shown in saved file). I've done this many times previously.I'm using a Mac.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
